# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH when opening Github

Tags: google-chrome, github

I am getting `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` error when opening github (specifically `https://github.com/`). Is something wrong with the server or is my browser set up incorrectly?

I have chrome 38 on Lubuntu 13.

Firefox 24 says:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to github.com. Cannot
>   communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
>   (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

Comment: Which exact URL are you pointing your browser at? Have you tried using some other browser, to rule out Chrome-specific issues?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling `https://github.com/`

Comment: I have the same problem. Might be country specific.

Comment: Errors on both mozilla and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome v40:

Open chrome://flags

Look for "Minimum SSL/TLS version supported."

Choose SSLv3

Click on "Relaunch now" button

Open your https page again

You will be redirected to a "Your connection is not private" page. If you do not worry about this security issue click on the "Advanced" link.

Finally click on "Proceed to (your https page) (unsafe)".

Solved.

Comment: Not solved. This flag does not exist anymore, yet the error still remains.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem using both Chrome version 46.0.2490.86 m and MS Edge on a Windows 10 laptop with the latest service pack installed and nothing helped until I uninstalled then reinstalled my Bitdefender antivirus.  It now works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of chrome and firefox disabled ssl3.0

Comment: Actually this does a pretty good job of explaining the reason